# How do I say "for + there be" correctly?

Tags: sentence-construction

I want to say

> This method is only used for there is no real error code.

I think "for" always links "doing", so this sentence is grammatically wrong. Or maybe I could say,

> This method is only used for situation that there is no real error
>   code.

But I think it may be clumsy. Or

> This method is only used for no real error.

What's your opinion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word "when" can help you out.

> This method is only used ***when*** there is no real error code.
>
> This method is only used for situations ***when*** there is no real error code.

Comment: Also, it should be "used only" rather than "only used". "only used" means "When there is no real error code, nothing is done with this method other than using it".

Comment: I don't think I'm following your logic.

Comment: @Accumulation I don't agree with that. "only used" is equivalent to "used only".

Comment: @Mixolydian People use the former to mean the latter, but that doesn't mean that there isn't a distinction.

Comment: I do agree that "only used" can mean "just used and nothing else" but I also think "used only" can mean the same thing - it depends on the context.

Comment: @Acccumulation "When there is no real error code, nothing is done with this method other than using it"  I don't mean to offend, but this sentence doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Mixolydian It can mean that, in the sense that people will be able to figure out what you mean; people have a tendency to prioritize what meaning makes sense over what the words should mean.

Comment: @DonB What do you mean "Doesn't make sense"? Do you mean it doesn't convey a coherent claim? That the claim is is absurd? Something else?

Comment: @Acccumulation Let me ask you a question: What would you do with a method other than using it?

Comment: @Acccumulation  Could you put into the form of a rule when one should say "only used" and when one should say, "used only?" That would make it really easy for me to understand what you mean. If there is a real distinction, you should be able to do that.

Comment: @DonB. You seem to be asserting the second option that I listed (that the claim is absurd). That it asserts an absurd claim is exactly why I am saying it is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

**for** as a conjunction can also be used **to introduce the reason for something mentioned in the previous statement**

> We listened eagerly, for he brought news of our families.
>   
>   Only this method is used ,**for** there is no real error code.

The above sentence is correct. But your other two sentences are not idiomatic.

Comment: There would have to be a comma before "for", and the meaning would be different. "Only this method is used, for there is no real error code." would mean "There is no error code, therefore this method is used."

Comment: @Acccumulation, oh, I just sense the difference. My original meaning was that "This method only can be used in no-real-error-code situation." The sentence in this answer means "In the no-real-error-code situation, only this method can be used."

Answer (score 1):

You have "only" at the wrong place; it should be "used only".

You need a noun phrase as an object for "for". The reason "doing" works is that it's a gerund, and gerunds act like nouns. If you put "when there is" before the phrase, then that acts like as a noun as well; "when there is no error code" means "the time at which there is no error code". You can also enclose the phrase in quotes, e.g. "This method is only used for 'there is no real error code'.". By enclosing the phrase in quotes, the string of words, rather than their meaning, becomes the object of "for".